# Can someone who is not wearing tefillin on a weekday receive an aliyah?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, torah-reading

My shul has a policy that anyone (male, over Bar Mitzva, of course) not wearing tefillin cannot receive an aliyah. Is there any halacha or minhag to support this rule?

My rav is in Eretz Yisra'el, now, so I cannot ask him directly.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no Halacha or Minhag that supports this policy. Perhaps this was instituted in your Shul to avoid giving an Aliya to individuals that are not Shomer Shabbos or for some other reason.

Comment: @GershonGold - No - I asked about that and it is specifically those not wearing tefillin. The majority of shul members are not Shomer Shabbat, and such people get aliyot on Shabbat itself, let alone on weekdays as well, if they wear tefillin during davening.

Comment: Perhaps it is done in order to get people to wear Tefilin?

Comment: @GershonGold - Possible, but doubtful. There's a regular minyanaire who never wears tefillin, but we're grateful he's there to help make the minyan. Granted, he may be an exception to your idea.

Comment: @DanF, I don't know, but outright refusal to wear Tefillin may be different than simply not happening to be wearing at that time (say you already davened in an earlier minyan, or whatever).

Comment: Perhaps it's a lo sisgodedu issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Hmmm .. that makes sense. IY"H, I'll find out the reason in a day or so. I think the reason may be "simpler" than I surmised.

Comment: I used to pray often at a certain chassidic minyan factory.  They had a rule that no one could get an aliyah if they weren't wearing a gartel (cloth belt).  They still called me up for aliyah l'torah, often.  A  chassid would simply remove his gartel, and lend it to me, so that I could go up and take my aliyah, in accordance with their custom.  I hope the shul in this question does the same, and loans a pair of tefillin, instead of simply ignoring the non-tefilling wearers, and skipping over them for aliyos l'torah.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion which I admit is not totally supported by the quoted source.

[www.torah.org](http://www.torah.org/learning/livinglaw/5767/eikev.html?print=1) has an article on tefillin from which I abstracted some lines which might be put together to justify the policy of your shul.

In short I am thinking that the shul might think that to read from the Torah one needs a clean body (guf noki) and that someone not wearing tefillin might not have a guf noki.

> The relationship between tefillin and Torah is very significant:
>
> 1 The very mention of tefillin in to be found in the context of Torah
>   learning: "You shall teach them [the Torah] thoroughly to your
>   children…Bind them as a sign upon your arm and let them be totafos
>   (tefillin) between your eyes" (Devarim 6:7-8).
>
> The tefillin house four Torah passages (Shemos 13:1-10, Shemos
>   13:11-16, Devarim 6:4-9 & Devarim 11:13 -21) which are written on
>   parchment like a Torah scroll.
>
> 2 **One who wears tefillin is compared to one who is reading from the
>   Torah (Pesikta Zutrasa Shemos 13).**
>
> 3 Torah in its entirety is compared to tefillin (Makkos 11a, Rosh
>   Hashanah 17a).
>
> And in the same way that the holiness of Torah housed in the tefillin
>   demands the wearer to have a clean body (guf noki) to wear these
>   religious artifacts (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 38:1-2), so too,
>   should the holiness of Torah indeed filter down and spiritualize our
>   physical bodies.

Comment: @AvrohomYitchok - To me, item 3 seems to lend stronger support than the guf noki analogy. I'll have to pass this one onto my rav when he returns, shortly. If his reasoning is drastically different, b"n, I'll post it, here.